# template in python

Tags: python, string, templates, format

How to write a function render_user which takes one of the tuples returned by userlist and a string template and returns the data substituted into the template, eg:

```
>>> tpl = "<a href='mailto:%s'>%s</a>"
>>> render_user(('matt.rez@where.com', 'matt rez', ), tpl)
"<a href='mailto:matt.rez@where.com>Matt rez</a>"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 12):

No urgent need to create a function, if you don't require one:

```
>>> tpl = "<a href='mailto:%s'>%s</a>"
>>> s = tpl % ('matt.rez@where.com', 'matt rez', )

>>> print s
"<a href='mailto:matt.rez@where.com'>matt rez</a>"
```

If you're on 2.6+ you can alternatively use the new `format` function along with its mini language:

```
>>> tpl = "<a href='mailto:{0}'>{1}</a>"
>>> s = tpl.format('matt.rez@where.com', 'matt rez')

>>> print s
"<a href='mailto:matt.rez@where.com'>matt rez</a>"
```

Wrapped in a function:

```
def render_user(userinfo, template="<a href='mailto:{0}'>{1}</a>"):
    """ Renders a HTML link for a given ``userinfo`` tuple;
        tuple contains (email, name) """
    return template.format(userinfo)

# Usage:

userinfo = ('matt.rez@where.com', 'matt rez')

print render_user(userinfo)
# same output as above
```

Extra credit:

Instead of using a normal `tuple` object try use the more robust and human friendly [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) provided by the `collections` module. It has the same performance characteristics (and memory consumption) as a regular `tuple`. An short intro into named tuples can be found in this PyCon 2011 Video (fast forward to ~12m): http://blip.tv/file/4883247

Comment: Thanks a lot,but I have to write it with function ,Is it similar to above codes or I should add more codes?

Comment: @miku Could you add detail about using a named tuple? The blip.tv file has been removed, and PyCon 2011 lists many results on youtube... I've checked a couple of related SO answers, and haven't found a clear example yet (obv didn't understand the documentation) - TIA!

Answer (score 4):

```
from string import Template
t = Template("${my} + ${your} = 10")
print(t.substitute({"my": 4, "your": 6}))
```